# run php eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: php, eclipse

i never used eclipse before now i installed **eclipse 3.2** in my pc which runs on **ubuntu** platform. Is any additional thing need to be installed for **php**? how start of my sample php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse offers a package optimized for PHP-Developers. Make sure, you go to the [Eclipse Download Page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and download "Eclipse for PHP Developers". This will give you everything you need to start developing PHP with Eclipse.

In order to start you have to create a new project and start coding ;)